# How to ignore NULL in a MySql query

Tags: mysql

I have the following query in MySql.

```
select source, count(*) as count from cs
```

How to ignore the NULL resuls ?

Thanks.

Comment: can u be more specific on this , what do you mean by ignoring NULL ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select source, count(*) as count from cs where source is not null
```